# Check if date is between or equal to two other dates

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to check if a date is between two other dates. The two other dates are coming from two DatePickers formatted as dd/mm/yyyy. My code below works but if my searching date is i.e. equal to the from date I get a "Not between" message. If I search for date 17/05/2013 and I set the ranges to bet from: 17/05/2013 and to: 17/05/2013 I want to get a "Between" message. Any ideas?

```
Dim str As String = "srt_inlbp_20130517"
Dim sString As String

sString = str.Substring(str.Length - 8)
Dim dTableDate As Date = Date.ParseExact(str.Substring(str.Length - 8), "yyyyMMdd", Nothing)

Label9.Text = dTableDate

If ((dTableDate >= dFromDate.Value) And (dTableDate <= dToDate.Value)) Then
        MsgBox("between")
Else
        MsgBox("not between")
End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have rewritten your code in this testable format:

```
Dim str As String = "srt_inlbp_20130517"

Dim dTableDate As Date = _
    Date.ParseExact(str.Substring(str.Length - 8), "yyyyMMdd", Nothing)

Dim dFromDate As New DateTime(2013, 5, 17)
Dim dToDate As New DateTime(2013, 6, 17)

If ((dTableDate >= dFromDate) And (dTableDate <= dToDate)) Then
    Console.WriteLine("between")
Else
    Console.WriteLine("not between")
End If
```

I get the result "between" so I can only suspect that your `dFromDate.Value` and/or `dToDate.Value` are not as you expect them to be. Can you check this please?

Comment: Your suspicion was correct. The variable dFromDate.Value was returning the time as well. I have changed it to dFromDate.Value.Date and it works.

Answer (score 3):

Try to write your comparators like you are reading a number line (e.g. always use a less-than sign).

```
Dim questionableDate As Date = New Date(2013, 05, 17)
Dim fromDate As Date = New Date(2013, 05, 17)
Dim toDate As Date = New Date(2013, 05, 17)

If (fromDate <= questionableDate) AndAlso (questionableDate <= toDate) Then
    MsgBox("between")
Else
    MsgBox("not between")
End If
```

You'll see that by using the number line approach you can easily determine what the code is doing.  The from date and to date are at the ends with the questionable date sandwiched in the middle.

#### Note

If the code above does not wield the results you expect once you integrate it, then you will need to set some breakpoints and step through your code to see exactly what values your variables have.

Comment: Nice code. I have fixed the error by adding dFromDate.Value.Date